# Django render api form into html and post to create new item

Tags: django

views.py

```
class CreateProduct(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'product-create.html'

    def get(self, request):
        serializer = item_serializer
        return Response({'serializer': serializer})

    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # print(request.data)
            serializer = item_serializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                return Response({'serializer': serializer})
            else:
                print('this post request is failure')
```

product-create.html

```
% extends "layouts/base.html" %}
{% load rest_framework %}

{% block title %} Create Item {% endblock %}

<!-- Specific CSS goes HERE -->
{% block stylesheets %}{% endblock stylesheets %}

{% block content %}
<div class="pcoded-content">
    <div class="pcoded-inner-content">

        <div class="main-body">
            <div class="page-wrapper">
                <h1>Create Products</h1>

                <form action="" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% render_form serializer %}
                    <input type="submit" value="Save">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

<!-- Specific Page JS goes HERE  -->
{% block javascripts %}{% endblock javascripts %}
```

want to render the api serializer into html, i did it by getting the visualize form, but the post method didt work and i get this error.

```
expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`
```

how do i get the post method to work and get the create the API ?